# Accessing couchdb futon thru https

Tags: nosql, couchdb, couchdb-futon

I've got a problem accessing futon interface when it is proxied using nginx.
This config works fine when http protocol is used, but when I try to use
https, I constantly receive `no_db_file` errors (but operations succeed,
e.g. I can create databases, insert values, etc.)

```
location / {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5984;
}
```

What can I do to make it work correctly using https protocol?

Comment: https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Nginx_As_a_Reverse_Proxy found now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Apache proxying to proxy https to http to do https on CouchDB: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Apache_As_a_Reverse_Proxy

I have found that a trailing slash on the URL affects whether or not https proxying works.  Maybe it affects Nginx the same way?

Answer (score 0):

That's not bad! At least you have a working link between nginx and CouchDB.

`no_db_file` is CouchDB's 404 response when a database (the first thing after the slash) is not there. Check the logs and see what path CouchDB actually received in the query. It may be one of the AJAX calls that Futon does; but whatever it is, the logs will say.